# Unable to compute Total and add/delete rows from table in html

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-tables

I am currently using the example from http://jsfiddle.net/QAa35/.
I tried to run the code snippet in my Chrome/IE browser but I am unable to get the results as shown in the fiddle.
Here is what I have in my `index.html`, which is exactly the same as the fiddle:

```
<table class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="product" /></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="price" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Product" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                Grand Total: $<span id="grandtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter++;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>$<input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>$<input type="text" name="linetotal' + counter + '" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);

        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"], input[name^="qty"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });
});

function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
    var qty = +row.find('input[name^="qty"]').val();
    row.find('input[name^="linetotal"]').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="linetotal"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
</script>
```

However, I am unable to get the total. I can't add/delete rows as well:
[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0aMD.png)

How can I make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code requires jQuery. So you just forgot to include it to your project or did it incorrectly. You can import jQuery from cdn just by adding this script to your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To prove that everything works fine with jQuery, here is your code with imported jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter++;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>$<input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td>$<input type="text" name="linetotal' + counter + '" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);

        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"], input[name^="qty"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });
});

function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
    var qty = +row.find('input[name^="qty"]').val();
    row.find('input[name^="linetotal"]').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="linetotal"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="product" /></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="price" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Product" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                Grand Total: $<span id="grandtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! it works by including the link! However, I have included local jQuery but it does not seems to work.. I believe the directory is correct. I included it this way: <script src="jquery/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @justalearner, I can't really say is it a right way to include without looking at your project's structure. But nice to hear, that my answer helped you!